# Display Data On Modal Screen Based On User Selection Using Check Box

Tags: checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

"I've displayed `20` records in navigation tab and against each records I've added coloumn for checkbox. My requirement is if user selects records (row) 1, 4, 8 using checkbox and click on "Edit" button on top of Navigation tab then it should display on `Modal` screen so that user can edit it.

if he/she selects records `5, 8, 6` then records should be display in that particular order.

I google it but couldn't find any related posts.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="RecordApp" ng-controller="recordcontroller" class="container-fluid">

    <div class="input-group">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="menu" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" >User Data</a></li>
        </ul>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>
                        <a href="#">Select</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="SortBy = 'Test1'; Reverse = !Reverse;">Test1</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="SortBy = 'Test2'; Reverse = !Reverse;">Test2</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="SortBy = 'Test3'; Reverse = !Reverse;">Test3</a>
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="record in Records | orderBy:SortBy:Reverse ">



                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" ng-model="record.Selected" ng-change="Checked(record)" />
                    </td>

                    <td>{{ record.Test1  }}</td>
                    <td>{{ record.Test2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ record.Test3 }}</td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

following is my `AngularJs` code for populating the navigation tab

```
  $http.get(pageBaseUrl + "api/records").success(function (records) {
        $scope.Records = records;
        $scope.IsLoading = false;
    });
```

Below is the code of Button and Modal screen:

```
 <div class="input-group">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#editRecords" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                        Edit Multiple Records
                    </button>
                </div>

    <div id="editRecords" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h2>Edit Data For Selected Records </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table-condensed table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Test 1</th>
                                <th>Test 2</th>
                                <th>Test 3</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="record in Records | orderBy:SortBy:Reverse">
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="SaveRecords();">Save Records</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="UnmarkForEdition()">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is the button for edit? Where is the modal HTML?

Comment: My bad. It should on top of navigation tab. Since I'm currently playing with my code so forgotten to mention it.

Comment: can you share the modal HTML and button code also, please!

Comment: Ok. Let provide you.

Comment: @NarenMurali I've updated my question with Button and Modal screen code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the code, here is my solution,

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Issues:**

First I check if the object contains any selected checkboxes using the code.

```
$scope.checkCheckbox = function(){
    return $filter('filter')($scope.Records, {Selected: true}).length === 0; 
 }
```

In the above code, I check the `ng-repeat` array if there is any object containing the property `Selected:true`, if there are none, then the length will be zero which using a comparator operator, I return a boolean. This is used by the HTML element `button` attribute `ng-disabled` and disables the input.

```
 <button type="button" ng-disabled="checkCheckbox()" data-target="#editRecords" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
              Edit Multiple Records
            </button>
```

When the `edit multiple records, button is clicked, I open the modal, and in the code I have added a simple`ng-if` which will show only the inputs where the checkbox is selected!

```
<tr ng-if="record.Selected" ng-repeat="record in Records | orderBy:SortBy:Reverse">
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" /></td>
                            </tr>
```

Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Excellent dear !! This is the logic which I'm looking for. Will you please do two more things: 1. display navigation tab records also on Modal screen while editing and records on modal screen should appear in a order user selected the checkbox. like if three records in navigation tabs are Record 1: - Test1 = 1, Test2 = 2, Test3 = 3 Record 2: - Test1 = 1.1, Test2 = 2.1, Test3 = 3.1 and Records 3: Test1 = 1.2, Test2 = 2.2, Test3 = 3.3 and user selected Record 2 and 1 then modal screen first show Record 2 then Record 1. Thank you once again!!

Comment: @ShalabhSaxena You can do that right? I wanted to help you with your issue alone!

Comment: Ok @naren Murali. Let me complete this. Thank you so much for helping me. Much appreciated.

Comment: apologies but couldn't make. I'm very new to angularjs and started working on angularjs since one week. I know the logic should be iterate through the array and select checked records but I spend 4 hours and still no sucess. Will you please help me as I'm running out of time?

Comment: Today, I give a fresh try and I was able to display the data on modal screen.